# Beautiful soup in Databricks

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have spark data frame  with customer I’d ,e-mail I’d and html column.Html column is a sting field which contains html tittle body etc.
my goal is extract email body and email subject for all these records and save it in two new columns for each row.
Example data set

Cust_id email_id email html

1. ```
    Abc_001. <! Doctype html >
   ```
2. ```
    Abc_200. <!doctype html>
   ```

I was able to the following result for one variable usin g the following code
Print ( BeautifulSoup(html).title.text

And for body

Tag = BeautifulSoup(html).body
For string in tag.strings:
Print(string)

Can some help with code in spark for reference. Thank you all members

I was able to the following result for one variable usin g the following code
Print ( BeautifulSoup(html).title.text

And for body

Tag = BeautifulSoup(html).body
For string in tag.strings:
Print(string)

Can some help with code in spark for reference. Thank you all members.